# How to Investigate - Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am modifying an ASP.NET MVC site that uses a lot of JQuery.
When I view the "Sources" in Chrome, There's an error message in one of my .cshtml files "**Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression**". The message is not near any of the JQuery or JavaScript code. It appears above a reference to a .CSS file.

_Layout.cshtml code -

```
<head>
<title>My Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/myCSS.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Rendered code -

```
<head>

    **Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression**

<link href="/Content/myCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I'm not sure if this error is causing an actual issue with the site because it's under construction. Usually errors like this appear around JQuery code, so I can more easily tell what the issue may be related to. I was wondering - **how I can investigate what is causing this issue?** Is there someway to tell what exactly is causing the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Show us the `View`-.csHtml code, the rendered HTML is not enough.

Comment: Thanks gdoron! I added it to the question.

Comment: The error line can be false if the error is occurred in a file loaded dynamically. Are you using AJAX to load some code? If yes, check the network tab of the debugger panel and check if one of the loaded script return an error

Comment: Thanks sdespont! I checked the network tab, but I see no error.